# iOS MKMapView Center on User Location and then allow unlimited Scrolling in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I don't believe this question has been asked yet in Swift 3.0 - three goals:

1. Upon `viewDidLoad` the Map Centers to the User Location at a certain zoom level that can be set (for example `let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(40.0, 40.0)`)
2. Once the map loads and centers on the User Location, the User can then move and scroll the map to any other location WITHOUT the map automatically snapping back to the original User Location
3. Allow the User to ONLY zoom in to a certain level but allow the User to zoom out fully to view the entire global map (no restrictions on the zoom out level)

Here is my code thus far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(40.0, 40.0)
        let userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true   
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Should work with the code you have now.

#### 2. Add check for subsequent location updates

In the `didUpdateLocations` method, add a `Bool` to check whether the region was centered on the user already or not.

```
var regionHasBeenCentered = false

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]

    if !regionHasBeenCentered {
        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(40.0, 40.0)
        let userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        regionHasBeenCentered = true
    }

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true   
}
```

Now the map will no longer center on the user after the first update, until you change `regionHasBeenCentered` back to `false`. This will allow the user to scroll and zoom freely.

#### 3. Implement `MKMapViewDelegate` method to detect map region changes

Implement `MKMapViewDelegate` on your view controller so that you can check for region changes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
```

…and set the view controller as the `delegate`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // other things…

    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Then implement the following method which will be called right before the region changes. Here you can check to see if the span's dimensions are too small, and set them to a minimum appropriate.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta <= 40 && mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta <= 40 {
         let minimumSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 40, longitudeDelta: 40)
         let minimumRegion= MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.centerCoordinate, span: minimumSpan)
         mapView.setRegion(minimumRegion, animated: false)
    }
}
```

**Important note:** From the [`MKCoordinateSpan` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinatespan), the `longitudeDelta` will change as you move toward/away from the equator.

> **longitudeDelta**
>
> The amount of east-to-west distance (measured in degrees) to display for the map region. The number of kilometers spanned by a longitude range varies based on the current latitude. For example, one degree of longitude spans a distance of approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles) at the equator but shrinks to 0 kilometers at the poles.

Furthermore, `MKCoordinateSpan`'s dimensions are measured in degrees, and 40 degrees is quite a bit so you probably want to change these values, otherwise the user will not be able to zoom in much at all.

Comment: Thanks so much @Paolo - #2 works great.  One final question on #3, where do you place the new method in the code (can you show the final code)

Comment: for #3 I placed the new function just before the override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @ServerProgrammer oops I forgot to add the setting of the delegate. I have updated my answer (see `viewDidLoad()`)

Comment: can you help me on one last tweak to your answer, when the map snaps back to the minimum dimensions, can you 'ease' this snap back so it is not so abrupt (almost like a bounce back animation or ease animation)?  Many thanks

Comment: @ServerProgrammer changed `animated: false` to `animated: true`

Comment: Thanks - however when I change animated to 'true' the map does snap back nicely but then it locks up and you can no longer navigate it

Comment: Hi @Paolo - I have set animated back to 'true' and the map snaps back nicely, but then it locks up and you can no longer navigate the map - any thoughts?

Comment: I have also posted another question that you may want to take a look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434894/ios-add-custom-annotation-and-then-pass-variables-to-a-new-view-controller-via-a

Comment: @Paolo I'm not sure what the 40 degrees in regionWillChangeAnimate does because I changed all four 40s to 0.01 and I kept having zoom problems because it would bounce back from 0.01 to something higher. The first part of your answer using a Bool for regionHasBeenCentered definitely worked so i upvoted it for that. Thanks