# How to add Custom Image to Annotation via a Subclass - Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

I would like to add a custom image for a callout annotation via a subclass (previous questions did not include using a subclass)

Here is my code thus far:

Subclass named "Capital.swift"

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var info: String

    // here we would add the custom image

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.info = info

     // add additional lines as needed

    }
}
```

Here is my code for the ViewController.swift

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")
        let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")
        let paris = Capital(title: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508), info: "Often called the City of Light.")
        let rome = Capital(title: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5), info: "Has a whole country inside it.")
        let washington = Capital(title: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667), info: "Named after George himself.")

        mapView.addAnnotations([london, oslo, paris, rome, washington])
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let identifier = "Capital"
        if annotation is Capital {
            if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) {
                annotationView.annotation = annotation
                return annotationView
            } else {
                let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:identifier)
                annotationView.isEnabled = true
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            return annotationView
         }
       }
        return nil
    }
```

Here we add the custom image to the annotationView

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        let capital = view.annotation as! Capital
        let placeName = capital.title
        let placeInfo = capital.info

        // Add custom image

        let SecondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
        self.show(SecondViewController!, sender: nil)       
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map view's delegate, not the annotation object itself, decides the annotation view for an annotation. So you need to set the image in your implementation of the map view delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

If you want, your `Capitol` class could vend the correct image, for example:

```
class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var info: String
    var imageForAnnotationView: UIImage? {
        guard let title = title else { return nil }
        return UIImage(named: "\(title).jpg")
    }
…
```

You could rewrite your delegate implementation and obtain the image like so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Capital"
    guard let annotation = annotation as? Capital else { return nil }

    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:identifier)

    annotationView.annotation = annotation
    annotationView.isEnabled = true
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

    // set the image to the annotation view
    annotationView.image = annotation.imageForAnnotationView

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Brager - working on this now.  What do you do with the initialization code on the Capital subclass to accommodate the custom image?

Comment: Hi @Aaron Brager - I receive an initializer error.  Here is my entire project code (for clarification I am using the Capital subclass to pass variables to potentionally dozens of pins on the map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434894/ios-pass-variables-to-a-new-view-controller-via-a-subclass-and-dozens-of-map-pin

Comment: What error? My example assumes you can determine the image name from the title, but if you want to pass an image into the initializer that's fine — just make a property and set it like you're doing with `title`

Comment: Hi @Aaron Barger - I created (5) png images with the following names (london.png, oslo.png, paris.png, rome.png and washington.png) and updated the Capital class as suggested: `class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var info: String
    var imageForAnnotationView: UIImage? {
        guard let title = title else { return nil }
        return UIImage(named: "\(title).png")
    }`

Comment: @ Aaron Barger ...and secondly, I replaced my original mapView function in my question to exactly as you suggested but it still displays the default pin and not the custom image for the pins

Comment: @ Aaron Barger - as suggested your example can determine the image name from the title in the subclass called "Capital" (which is exactly what I am looking for - thank you).  I also capitalized the name of each image to London.png, Oslo.png, Paris.png, etc.  However, as I mentioned (hopefully I didn't miss something) the annotationView still only uses the default image for the pins and not the custom images.

Comment: Hi @Aaron Brager - I have updated the question and I also have a related question (using the same code) if you would like to view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459776/how-to-pass-variables-from-a-subclass-via-a-segue-to-a-secondviewcontroller

Comment: @ Aaron Barger - I have updated the code exactly as you suggested but it still displays the same original default pins?

Comment: Hi @Aaron Barger - thank you for your answer.  Here is a related question if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717839/add-modal-popup-to-map-annotation-swift-3-0