# How to Pass Variables from a Subclass via a Segue to a SecondViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a subclass called "Capital" that declares variables and I would like to push these variables via the subclass to a new SecondViewController via a segue

In addition to the subclass "Capital" I also have (2) ViewControllers: ViewController -> SecondViewController

**Here is my code for the subclass called "Capital"**

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var title: String?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var info: String
var imageForAnnotationView: UIImage? {
    guard let title = title else { return nil }
    return UIImage(named: "\(title).png")
}
init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.info = info
    }
}
```

**Here is my entire code for the first ViewController:**

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var capital:Capital!
@IBOutlet 
var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")
    let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")
    let paris = Capital(title: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508), info: "Often called the City of Light.")
    let rome = Capital(title: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5), info: "Has a whole country inside it.")
    let washington = Capital(title: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667), info: "Named after George himself.")

     mapView.addAnnotations([london, oslo, paris, rome, washington])
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Capital"
    guard let annotation = annotation as? Capital else { return nil }

    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:identifier)

    annotationView.annotation = annotation
    annotationView.isEnabled = true
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

    // set the image to the annotation view
    annotationView.image = annotation.imageForAnnotationView

    return annotationView
```

**// additional code**

```
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    // let capital = view.annotation as! Capital
    // let placeName = capital.title
    // let placeInfo = capital.info

    self.capital = view.annotation as! Capital

    let SecondViewController =
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
    self.show(SecondViewController!, sender: nil)     
    }
}
```

**Here is my code for the SecondViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var text1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var text3: UILabel!

var selectedCapital:Capital!
var myString = String()
var placeName = String()
var placeInfo = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    text1.text = myString
    text2.text = placeName
    text3.text = placeInfo

    print(self.selectedCapital)
}}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first ViewController create a global variable with type `Capital`. Assign value tot the variable in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` function and perform segue. In SecondViewController create a global variable with type `Capital` and pass value in `prepare for segue`

**First View Controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var capital:Capital!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let secViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

        // push the title, info and other optional variables
        secViewController.selectedCapital = self.capital
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        self.capital = view.annotation as! Capital
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecViewControlle", sender: self)
    }
}
```

---

**Second ViewController**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedCapital:Capital!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.selectedCapital)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning         self.capital = view.annotation as! Capital
in calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Comment: Thanks @Rajeshkumar R - I have updated the code as suggested (please see above) but I receive "nil" in the console?

Comment: @ServerProgrammer In which line you get nil?

Comment: Hi @Rajeshkumar R - I just provided the code for the SecondViewController.  In this final VC it contains (3) labels that I want to assign the values contained in the global variable Capital

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155545/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-server-programmer).

Comment: Hi @Rajeshkumar R - it still returns a 'nil' in the console, available in chat

Comment: Here is the larger question I am trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434894/ios-pass-variables-to-a-new-view-controller-via-a-subclass-and-dozens-of-map-pin

Comment: Hi @Rajesh - thank you for your answer.  Here is a related question if you would like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717839/add-modal-popup-to-map-annotation-swift-3-0